# Is it possible to install capybara-webkit with xcode command line tools only?

Tags: xcode, capybara-webkit

The last computer I installed capybara-webkit on did not require full xcode, only the command line tools.  However, now when I try to install it on a new computer, I run into the following:

Try to install: 
`$ gem install capybara-webkit`

Get error about license: `Project ERROR: Xcode not set up properly. You may need to confirm the license agreement by running /usr/bin/xcodebuild.`

Try to accept license: `$ xcodebuild -license`

Get error about only having command line tools: `xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

At this point I've just given up and started installing xcode, but it seems silly that I have to install a 4.5GB IDE just so I can accept a license agreement for the command line tools.  Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in [capybara-webkit wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#video-playback-mp4-on-osx-requires-qt-5) and in [QT wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.4.0_Known_Issues#QtWebEngine), it is not possible, as **capybara-webkit** requires **QT**.

*Qt 5 sadly requires the full Xcode to be installed (> 5 GB), as opposed to previous versions of Qt which didn't. NB: We warn against using tools that try to avoid installing the full Xcode by overwriting system files in /usr/bin, since that has caused problems for other users, forcing them to reinstall OSX.*

*Building on OSX currently requires at least XCode version 5.1. This will remain a requirement for Qt WebEngine. Changing it would require significant changes to the Chromium code base that are going against the direction Chromium is being developed.*